# How to get size of an element in physical pixels?

Tags: html, canvas

Let's say i have a `div` that i've defined to be `(32px, 32px)` in size:

**html**:

```
<div id="theBox"></div>
```

**css**:

```
div {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

([Live jsFiddle view](http://jsfiddle.net/cnCm5/))

How can i get the actual size of the box in pixels?

You'll note that the box doesn't have to be `32px`. It can be larger:

[image]

or smaller:

[image]

or exactly `32 pixels`:

[image]

The reason for the differences, of course, is because Chrome and Internet Explorer allow me to *zoom*.

i would like to know the ***actual*** size of the element. Why? No reason; just cause. i'm curious, and i'd like to broaden the limits of human knowledge and understanding.

Or because i need to set the internal resolution of a `Canvas` element to match the *actual* size of the canvas element - otherwise the rendered canvas contents will get stretched without my permission:

[image]

Although, my reasons for wanting to know the size of an element do not necessarily apply just to a Canvas. i'm asking about a generic div element; and the answer will be used towards `canvas`, `img`, `video`, and anything else i desire.

Comment: interesting question , does this answer help you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5078596/188331 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to detect the zoom level.

Then write a simple arithmetic proportion to calculate the 'actual' size, or the size as it appears to the user.

```
var zoomLevel,
, actualSize = 32
, viewSize;
function getZoomLevel(){ ... your code here...return zoomLevel;}

function getViewSize(actualSize){
  viewSize = actualSize*getZoomLevel();
  return viewSize;
}
```

Then ... call `getViewSize()` when ready ...

Hopefully the math is clear enuff. 
Solving for y (or viewSize):

```
actualSize/1 = y/zoomLevel
```

However, you will need to be careful about sub-pixel precision, especially among the notoriously bad length/width determining browsers like IE9. But, as long as all you need is something close, this should work.